# independence of gamma random variables - is this correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, gamma-distribution

Suppose $X \sim \Gamma[n_1,\lambda], Y \sim \Gamma[n_2,\lambda]$,
and $X+Y \sim \Gamma[n_1 + n_2, \lambda]$

**Can we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?**

Here's what I think: 
Suppose $f,g$ are p.d.f.'s of $X,Y$, and $h$ be their joint p.d.f. It is basically saying

$$ \forall z>0,\int_0^z h(x,z-x)dx = \int_0^z f(x)g(z-x)dx $$

**Does it infer $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ a.e.?**

Well, I know that if 
$$ \int_0^xf(u)du = \int_0^x g(u)du$$
By taking the derivative of $x$, I suppose it means $f = g$ a.e.

However, I don't know how to take the derivative of $z$ in the previous formula, since $x$ appears at the same time with $z$. If I take the derivative of $z$, since $z-z=0$, I'll get $h(z,0) = f(z)g(0)$, which doesn't seem to help.

We know that if $X$, $Y$ are independent, the additivity holds. Now I'm doing a problem that requires to prove the independence of two r.v.'s. I found that they follow Gamma distributions and they obey additivity, but I'm not sure if it is legitimate to say these two r.v.'s are independence.

Thanks!

Comment: You assume independence when using this formula: $\int_0^z h(x,z-x)dx = \int_0^z f(x)g(z-x)dx $

Comment: @zoli Indeed, but $\int_0^z f(x)g(z-x)dx$ is the p.d.f. of sum of two (assuming independent) gamma r.v.'s, which follows $\Gamma[n_1+n_2,\lambda]$, which happens to equates the left hand of the formula, which is the sum of X and Y. Is this right?

Comment: I mean, even if X and Y are not independent, the integral $\int f(x)g(z-x)dx$ still is the p.d.f. of $\Gamma(n_1+n_2, \lambda)$.

Comment: OK. I understand.

Comment: This is not true, I'll write shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of characteristic functions, the question is whether variables are independent if the product of their characteristic functions is equal to characteristic function of their sum: $$\mathbb E[e^{itX}]\cdot \mathbb E[e^{itY}] = \mathbb E[e^{it(X+Y)}].\tag{1}$$ We know that the variables are independent iff for all $t,s\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\mathbb E[e^{itX}]\cdot \mathbb E[e^{isY}] = \mathbb E[e^{i(tX+sY)}],$$
which is much stronger than $(1)$. So it should be obvious that the answer is negative. But it is not so easy to construct a particular example.

---

I will construct an example in the case where $n_1 = n_2 = 1$, $\lambda = 1$, so that we have $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ variables (if you'll understand this construction, then you'll be able to make a similar construction in arbitrary case).

Let us first reduce this problem to a discrete case, which is easier to handle. It is well known (and easy to prove) that for an exponentially distributed random variable $X$, its integer part $\lfloor X\rfloor$ and its fractional part $\{X\}$ are independent and the integer part has shifted geometrical distribution: 
$$
p_n := \mathbb{P}(\lfloor X\rfloor = n) = e^{-n}(1-e^{-1}), n\ge 0.
$$

---

So we want to construct two dependent variables $X'$, $Y'$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(X' = n) = \mathbb{P}(Y' = n) = p_n, n\ge 0,\tag{2}$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(X'+Y' = n) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_kp_{n-k}, n\ge 0.\tag{3}$$ Start by setting $p_{k,j} = p_kp_j$. Now, for some very small $\epsilon>0$ distort six values: 
\begin{eqnarray}
& & p'_{1,0}= p_{1,0}+\epsilon\quad & p'_{2,0}= p_{2,0}-\epsilon\\
& p'_{0,1}= p_{0,1}-\epsilon\quad & & p'_{2,1}= p_{2,1}+\epsilon \\
& p'_{0,2}= p_{0,2}+\epsilon\quad & p'_{1,2}= p_{1,2}-\epsilon & 
\end{eqnarray}
and set $\mathbb{P}(X' = k,Y'=j) = p'_{k,j}$ for these six values and $\mathbb{P}(X' = k,Y'=j) = p_{k,j}$ otherwise. It is easy to see that such $X',Y'$ are dependent and satisfy $(2)$ and $(3)$.

---

Finally, let $X'',Y''$ be independent random variables, which are independent of $X'$, $Y'$ and have the same distribution as fractional part of $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$.

Setting $X = X'+X''$, $Y = Y'+Y''$, we arrive at the required example.

Comment: It is not convincing that a similar example can be constructed for absolutely continuous Exponentialy distributed r.v.'s.  It's not so easy to spoil the joint density.  I have not succeeded so far.

Comment: @NCh, the construction *is* for absolutely continuous variables.

Comment: Oh, really. I missed everything concerns the fractional part. Sorry.